# onBackPressed() Best Practice/Performance

Tags: java, android, performance, back

I usually override `onBackPressed()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Only now I saw that when I click the back button with this code **I see for 0.5 sec a white activity in the transition.**

Testing a little bit I found that if I use this code instead the problem didn't happen:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**What's the difference between this two code? If I use the second one is fine? Cause any memory problem?** Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super.onBackPressed` just calls finish.  It isn't needed if you're calling finish yourself.  Just remove the line.

The reason you may see a visual difference is that in one you're finishing this intent then starting a new one, vs starting a new one then finishing this one.  The first may leave a blank screen briefly.

Comment: So there is no difference between super.onBackPressed() and finish() right?

Comment: Correct- unless another class in your ancestry already overrode it.  But I'm assuming that's not the case here.